# Steepest descent method proof in Nocedal & Wright

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

On Chapter 2, on unconstrained optimization, of Nocedal & Wright's [Numerical Optimization](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-40065-5), beginning on page 20, the authors verify that the steepest descent direction, $-\nabla f_k$ provides the direction along which the objective $f$ decreases most rapidly. I have some trouble following their proof.

Starting from Taylor's theorem,

$$f(x+p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T p + \frac{1}{2} p^T \nabla^2 f(x+tp)p$$

We have for the iterate $x_k$, step direction $p$ and step-length $\alpha$, $$f(x_k + \alpha p) = f(x_k) + \alpha p^T \nabla f_k + \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 p^T \nabla^2 f(x_k + tp)p$$

for some $t \in (0,\alpha)$. The text claims:

> The rate of change in $f$ along the direction $p$ at $x_k$ is simply the coefficient of $\alpha$, namely $p^T \nabla f_k$. Hence, the unit direction $p$ of most rapid decrease is the solution to the problem $$\min_{p} p^T \nabla f_k$$ subject to $|| p || = 1$.

How does the quoted text follow from Taylor's theorem? I can understand in general that the rate of change in $f$ along the direction of $p$ is the projection of $\nabla f_k$ on $p$ or $$\frac{p^T \nabla f_k}{||p||}$$ where we take $||p||=1$ here, but why did the text need to bring up Taylor's theorem here?

Comment: A related question: How is it that you can understand that the general rate of change in $f$ is given as you say, _without_ using the Taylor theorem?

Comment: The Taylor theorem is just to say that: $$ \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_k + \alpha p) - f(x_k)}{\alpha} = p^T\nabla f_k + \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0} \frac{\alpha p^T\nabla^2 f(x_k + t_{\alpha}p)p}{2}$$ and the limit in the last term on the right-hand-side is 0 if you assume $\nabla f^2$ is bounded over the interval of interest.

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense to me. I did not consider the mathematical definition of the rate of change at $x_k$, simply vector projection in basic physics/kinematics.

Comment: I suppose you do not need Taylor if you use the definition of derivative at a particular point $x_k$ to get $f(x_k+h) = f(x_k) + \nabla f_k \cdot h + error_k(h)$, where $error_k(h)$ satisfies $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{||error_k(h)||}{||h||} = 0$.  But the rate of decrease in that error term depends on the point $x_k$, and if you have bounds on $\nabla^2 f$ you can get universal error bounds (via Taylor) that hold for all points $x_k$.

Comment: Since the link to the PDF file is broken, I removed it.